# Popup is overflowing with overflow: auto, I don't get why

Tags: html, css

I know questions like that have been asked a few thousand times, but this thing drives me crazy.
I'm trying to create a simple popup, the height of the parent is set, if I set the height of the titlebar, it changes nothing.

Hope someone can help me with this, so I don't need to smash my keyboard today.

Thank you.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

#popup-window {
  position: absolute;
  ;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #50ed77;
  border: 1px solid #3E3B3B;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 800px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
}

#popup-window-titlebar {
  background-color: #21522d;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#popup-window-inner {
  margin: 5px;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#popup-window-list {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.window-close-btn {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.window-close-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ff115c;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-window">
  <div id="popup-window-titlebar">
    <b>Funny Title</b>
    <div class="window-close-btn">
      X
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="popup-window-inner">
    <div id="popup-window-list">
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Want to fix the overflow. Googled for 2 hours now and tried different attributes (position, height...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make your popup window flex with a direction of column, then you can make the inner flex grow (to take the remaining height of the popup after the title).

If you then make the inner relative, you can absolutely position your scroll div to fill the inner and then your overflow should work:

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

#popup-window {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #50ed77;
  border: 1px solid #3E3B3B;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 800px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  display:flex;                 /* make this flex with a direction of column */
  flex-direction:column;
}

#popup-window-titlebar {
  background-color: #21522d;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#popup-window-inner {
  margin: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;          /* make this grow to fill remaining space and also relative */
  position:relative;
}

#popup-window-list {
  position:absolute;   /* absolutely position this to fill inner - 5px below replaces your margin */
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  right:5px;
  bottom:5px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.window-close-btn {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.window-close-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ff115c;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-window">
  <div id="popup-window-titlebar">
    <b>Funny Title</b>
    <div class="window-close-btn">
      X
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="popup-window-inner">
    <div id="popup-window-list">
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I like your solution the most. Seems I still have a lot of stuff to learn. You saved the day. Thanks to the other guys as well.

Answer (score 1):

add overflow and change height of #popup-window

update style

```
#popup-window-inner {
    margin: 5px;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 76%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

#popup-window {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #50ed77;
  border: 1px solid #3E3B3B;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 800px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#popup-window-titlebar {
  background-color: #21522d;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0
}

#popup-window-inner {
  margin: 5px;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#popup-window-list {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.window-close-btn {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.window-close-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ff115c;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-window">
  <div id="popup-window-titlebar">
    <b>Funny Title</b>
    <div class="window-close-btn">
      X
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="popup-window-inner">
    <div id="popup-window-list">
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
      <div>Entry</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```